# How to get the scheduled events list in CALENDLY?

Tags: calendly

> Note: I do not want to use the calendly webhook.
> When I hit the API

> **`https://api.calendly.com/users/me`**

It will give me the 'current_organization' uri and user uri.

To get the scheduled events I need to call this API

> **https://api.calendly.com/scheduled_events?organization=2c93f482-emd0-0eh4-a0rd-c77429ec73e8**

The '**organization**' parameter contains the value I got from the '**users/me**' API, current_organization. However, the API returned an error with an invalid organization.

What should I have to provide in the '**organization**' or 'user' param in the get scheduled event list API of the calendly?

[Calendly API error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMqVm.png)

[Calendly docs](https://developer.calendly.com/api-docs/2d5ed9bbd2952-list-events)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue myself. Turns out, you need to provide the full URL instead of just an ID. For example, if your organization ID is XXXXXXXX, you need to pass `https://api.calendly.com/organizations/XXXXXXXX` in the parameters of the request like this:

```
GET https://api.calendly.com/scheduled_events?organization=https://api.calendly.com/organizations/XXXXXXXX
```

I wish they would've made it more clear in their documentation.